# search-forward-regexp with back reference

Tags: regular-expressions, search

I have the following text

```
\begin{comment}
TEXT
\end{comment}

\begin{verbatim}
TEXT
\end{verbatim}
```

and the regular expression `"\\begin{\([^}]*\)}` to match the `\begin` statements and capture the `comment` or `verbatim` words. Now, I would like to match the `\end` statements. Given I already had a match for `\begin` I thought I could reference the previous match and look for `\\end{\\1}`, however I am getting `Invalid back reference`. 
Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to reference previous matches in a regular expression?

Comment: Are you wanting to search for something like this? `"\\\\begin{\\([^}]*\\)}\n.*?\n\\\\end{\\1}"`

Comment: That's actually exactly what I wanted. It didn't cross my mind to use the one regex for both searches. Thanks you!

Comment: You're welcome.  I should add that, as `.` does not match newlines, the `.*?` should be `\\(.\\|\n\\)*?` if you needed it to match with arbitrary multi-line TEXT.

Answer (score 1):

The `\\1` construct is typically used when replacing the content.

If you do a search you have multiple options.

1) You could search for `\\end{\([^}]*\)}"` and manually check that the parts between the braces match the previous search.

2) You could create a regexp using normal string operations and search for it:

```
(concat "\\\\end{" (match-string 1) "}")
```

Comment: Thanks. For the second option, is there a way to do that more systematically from the regular expression `\\end{\\1}`? One way I thought would work is `(replace-regexp-in-string "\\begin{\([^}]*\)}" "\\\\end{\\1}" (match-string 0))`, but that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Correction: The expression `(replace-regexp-in-string "\\begin{\([^}]*\)}" "\\\\end{\\1}" (match-string 0))` does work. I am now just wondering if it's the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: In elisp, `"\\begin{\([^}]*\)}"` is the regexp `\begin{([^}]*)}` -- i.e. it starts with a word-boundary rather than "backslash followed by b", and there's no group, so it's not going to match.  `\\ ` and `\(` and `\)` all need to be escaped for the string read syntax.

Comment: What @phils is trying to say is that that when you write a regexp as a elisp string, you will need to write `"\\\\begin{\\([^}]*\\)}"`.